# Clickable cell not invoking onClick function

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

How do I create a clickable grid cell that can trigger a JavaScript function?

I provided this as a template for the column
template:

```
'<a href="\\#" class="group-details-popup">#=groupRefId#</a>'
```

and then added a function like this to search for that class and add a click listener:

```
$(".group-details-popup", grid.tbody).on("click", function (e) {
         // do something
});
```

but my function never gets invoked when I click on the cell; the values in the cell does show up as a link, but no event get triggered.

Comment: Are you adding rows dynamically on the page on to the grid?

Comment: Yes data is fetched once user makes a selection from a top level drop down box

Comment: Try this `$(grid.tbody).on("click", ".group-details-popup" ,function (e) {`

Comment: That seemed to work, thanks!

Comment: @PSL Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're getting an error when you try to access `grid.tbody` because it is undefined. You need to wrap it in quotes:

```
$(".group-details-popup", ".grid tbody").on("click", function (e) {
         // do something
});
```

I've assumed above that `grid` is a class and you want to bind the handler to `tbody` elements within that class. Otherwise, your jQuery is fine (assuming you have included it properly):

http://jsfiddle.net/GwYcf/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work, grid component is fine as I can see it in the debugger, also the corresponding grid.tbody looks good.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$("a.group-details-popup").click(function () {
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it this way:

```
$(".group-details-popup", grid.tbody).on("click", function (e) {
         // do something
});
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
$(grid.tbody).find(".group-details-popup").on("click", function (e) {
         // do something
});
```

Attaches a click event handler to the existing class "group-details-popup" inside the grip.tbody jQuery element reference.

In order to attach to a not yet existing element, you would need to attach the event handler to some wrapper for that element - something that holds the element once it is added.  One option is "document" however document is not a desired container if you can get something more precise so that the event handler does not have to process the entire DOM to find the target.  You seem to have an element wrapper so use that.

```
$(grid.tbody).on("click", ".group-details-popup", function (e) {
         // do something
});
```